# Windows Server 2008 Start menu classic style

Tags: windows-server-2008

After you switch the Start menu to the classic style on a computer that is running a version of Windows Server 2008 without Hyper-V, the Start menu is not displayed correctly. Specifically, a black area unexpectedly appears on the left side of the Start menu. Additionally, the Windows Server 2008 logo bar is displayed horizontally instead of vertically.

[alt text http://www.experts-exchange.com/images/t45491/Start-Menu.jpg](http://www.experts-exchange.com/images/t45491/Start-Menu.jpg)

How can I get rad of it ?

Comment: Weird, I don't get that, have you rebooted since or gone back to the standard interface then back again to classic?

Answer (score 1):

Should help you some.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950612

Comment: Anybody else find it a bit odd that the OPs question is *exactly* the same text as this Microsoft KB summary?

Comment: Hmm, never noticed that. That is a tad odd.

Comment: Whoa... yeah, seriously strange.  What are the odds?

Comment: Agreed - down voting